# insert one page content to the another page in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```html
<script src="jquery.js"></script> 
<header id="menu-header">

//menu bar

</header>

 <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#menu-header").load("header.html"); 
    });
    </script>
```

Here I want to include my header menu into different html pages. How to include one html header into each page? I have already used jQuery `load` function but it is not working in Chrome.

//menu bar

Comment: Please post your codes.

Comment: You can use some preprocessing languages like PHP, or use default js load functions to load html from other files

Comment: no iam using basic html,javascript,jquery

Comment: try making the header html as a string in js and use jQuery to assign the innerHtml as this string

Comment: You should be doing this server side, not client side. Loading your site's header via JS in the browser, on every page, sounds like a good way to slow your site down. Whichever server side language you use will have some sort of include function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do using `jQuery` Get Request.

For example here is `menu.html` file

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="www.naveedramzan.com" title="Home">Home</a>
    <li><a href="www.naveedramzan.com/about-naveed" title="About">About</a>
</ul>
```

Here is `index.html` file

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.get( "menu.html", function( data ) {
          $( "#menu" ).html( data );
        });
    });
</script>
```

jQuery will load menu.html file and add html in `#menu` and that you can do on all pages

Comment: thanks for your answer.but iam getting this error.  Failed to load file:///F:/abc%20TASK/dewi/header.html: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: @ravikumar: you should avoid to use physical file.

Comment: can you explain in detail,physical file in the sense

Comment: Means you should use `../dewi` or `filename.html` if its not in same folder.

Comment: in header.html,my menu bar code  is there.  In index.html i have to load header.html code..In index.html i have created div with id is #menu.In js file i wrote the script. this is the procedure i have followed.

Comment: and my files everything is in same folder

Comment: Kindly update or paste here that `.get` line I want to see the path

Comment: $.get( "header.html", function( data ) {

Comment: Yup its fine. It should be working. Can you share file at ping@naveedramzan.com

Comment: please check your mail

Answer (score 0):

This node.js library will help you; [templatesjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/templatesjs);